# Skip a line line in a tabWidget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Is it possible to skip a line in a tabWidget? So far I've tried \r and \n but nothing...Here is a sample code:

```
this.tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("deux").setIndicator("Alarme\n volontaire",
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_alert)).setContent(alarme);
this.tabHost.addTab(this.tabSpec);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something like this in my apps and it works:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("deux").setIndicator("Alarme\n volontaire"), null);
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    ((TextView) TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setSingleLine(false);
}
```